# How to call the textbox on the form in a module?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble calling the textbox on the form inside a module. Every time I run it, it throws a Compile Error: Method or data not found. This is my code:

```
Sub formInitialize()
    ThisWorkbook.txtDate.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Thank you for your great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your time. I have already figured out my problem.
I should not be using the `ThisWorkbook`, I should be calling the `formName`. The code is as follows:

```
Sub formInitialize()
    formName.txtDate.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Thank's again!